# In c#, how can i generate a set of strings like aa0000 > aa0001 >... > zz9999

Tags: c#, string

Hi everyone I need to generate all `string`s from `aa0000` to `zz9999`; where the first two position are only chars from `a` to `z` and the last four positions are from `0000` to `9999`.
I tried everything I could but I can't find a way to do this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if you have a not working code but you show it, is preferable than to ask just a question asking others to write code for you.

Comment: Do you have enough memory at your computer to keep  this set?

Comment: @Serge every string will be used and disposed before generating the next string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *nested loops*, e.g.

**Code:**

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> Generator() {
      for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; ++a)
        for (char b = 'a'; b <= 'z'; ++b)
          for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i)
            yield return $"{a}{b}{i:d4}";
    }

    ...

    foreach (string s in Generator()) {
      //TODO: Put relevant code here
    }
```

**Demo:**

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Generator()
      .Skip(1_000_000 - 5) // skip some items
      .Take(10)));         // then take some items

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write(Generator().Count()); // how many items do we have?
```

**Outcome:**

```
dv9995
dv9996
dv9997
dv9998
dv9999
dw0000
dw0001
dw0002
dw0003
dw0004 

6760000
```

Comment: I think you should be doing `a++` instead of `++a` and likewise for other variables, so that first item in loop is not skipped? I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar: both `++a` and `a++` have same effect; `++a` is my old `C` habbit: it time of old (when compiler must have fit 64k) it helps optimizing code.